# Notation question: set of times of certain events

Tags: functions

I have a function of time $t$ described as
$$f(t) = H(g(t) - 1)$$
where $$H(x)=\begin{cases} 0,& x<0\\1,&x\ge0\end{cases}$$ is the Heaviside step function and $g(t)$ is a continuous function.

Now, it want to have set $T$ that contains all the times at which a 0-to-1 or 1-to-0 transition occurs. Can I write that as:

$$T = \left\lbrace t \ \middle|\  \frac{\textrm{d} f(t)}{\textrm{d} t} \neq 0 \right\rbrace$$

or is there a better way?

Comment: $\frac{df}{dt}$ will be undefined or 0 so your definition cannot make sense. Your $f(t)$ will be 0 if $g(t)<1$ and 1 if $g(t)\ge 1$ so why not just have $T = \{t : g(t) = 1\}$?

Comment: @paul that works for me. If you put that in an answer, I'll give you the cred.

Comment: @Paul I see what you are trying to say, but what if $g$ is constantly $1$ (on some interval)? Then $T$ will be $1$ and will flag many nontransitions. I think the OP and  should just describe the set $T$ in words. That would be best for readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to describe this set for your readers is in words:

> Let $T$ be the set of times at which a $0$-to-$1$ or $1$-to-$0$ 
>   transition occurs in $f$ - that is, the transition times from sleep to waking
>   or vice versa.

Any mathematical notation - even good notation - would have to be decoded to be understaood.

I assume you don't need any kind of formula in your code.

Comment: Good suggestion. However, I've managed to describe everything else in mathematical equations in my paper. And if I then only would describe this in words, it would be quite inconsistent with the rest.

Comment: As a reader I often prefer words to equations, and certainly words to ad hoc  nonstandard notation. Readability would be more important to me than stylistic consistency.

Comment: I used words in the end. I first tried to describe everything in mathematics, but like you hint: I kept needing to introduce a new mathematical notation, having subscripts and subscripts of subscripts, etc. It was much easier and probably more clear to just explain it in words.

Comment: @JHBonarius Lesson learned - now and for the things you write from now on.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your step function (as defined) is arguably *not* a Heaviside step function, depending on what you mean by $g$ being "continuous." That said, it's sensible, regardless.

Secondly, I assume that the order in "0-to-1" and "1-to-0" indicates a left-to-right progression, since we're talking about time. Let me know if that's not correct, or if you aren't sure if that's correct.

Thirdly, I assume that $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,$ where both domain and codomain are considered in the standard topology for the purposes of determining continuity. Let me know if that is not correct, or if you aren't sure if that's correct.

So, under those assumptions, what might $T$ look like? Well, let's suppose that $t_0\in T,$ and proceed by cases.

---

First, let's suppose that there is a 0-to-1 transition at $t=t_0.$ Obviously, we must have either $f(t_0)=0$ or $f(t_0)=1,$ but which one? Well, if we have $f(t_0)=0,$ then by definition, we must have $g(t_0)-1<0,$ meaning that $g(t_0)<1.$ By continuity, letting $\epsilon=1-g(t_0)>0,$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<|t-t_0|<\delta,$ we have $|g(t)-g(t_0)|<\epsilon.$ In particular, if $t\in(t_0,t_0+\delta),$ then $$g(t)-g(t_0)\le|g(t)-g(t_0)|<\epsilon=1-g(t_0),$$ so we see that $g(t)-g(t_0)<1-g(t_0),$ so $g(t)<1,$ so $g(t)-1<0,$ and so $f(t)=0.$ Put another way, $f$ is identically $0$ on the interval $[t_0,t_0+\delta),$ so it doesn't make sense to talk about a "0-to-1 transition" happening at $t_0.$ Consequently, we *must* have $f(t_0)=1,$ meaning that $g(t_0)\ge 1.$ However, if we had $g(t_0)>1,$ then by similar arguments to the above, there would be some $\delta>0$ such that $f(t)=1$ for all $t\in(t_0-\delta,t_0],$ so that it makes no sense to talk about the transition happening at $t_0.$ Thus, we must have $g(t_0)=1,$ but if there is some $\delta>0$ for which $g(t)\ge1$ for all $t\in(t_0-\delta,t_0),$ then it *still* doesn't make sense to talk about the transition happening at $t_0.$ Thus, we have that $g(t_0)=1,$ and for all $\delta>0,$ we have that $$(t_0-\delta,t_0)\cap g^{-1}\bigl[(-\infty,1)\bigr]\neq\emptyset.$$ Here, for any $A\subseteq\Bbb R,$ I mean $$g^{-1}[A]:=\bigl\{t\in\Bbb R\mid g(t)\in A\bigr\}.$$

---

Now, let's suppose that there is a 1-to-0 transition at $t=t_0.$ As above, if $f(t_0)=0,$ then there is some $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<|t-t_0|<\delta,$ we have $|g(t)-g(t_0)|<1-g(t_0).$ In particular, if $t\in(t_0-\delta,t_0),$ then we have as above that $g(t)<1,$ so that $f$ is identically zero on $(t_0-\delta,t_0],$ and so we conclude that $f(t_0)=1,$ so $g(t_0)\ge 1.$ In a similar fashion to the work in the previous case, we likewise conclude that $g(t_0)=1,$ and that for all $\delta>0,$ we have $$(t_0,t_0+\delta)\cap g^{-1}\bigl[(-\infty,1)\bigr]\neq\emptyset.$$

---

Now, the above shows *necessary* conditions for $t_0$ to be an element of $T.$ I leave it to you to show that the conditions are also *sufficient*--that is, to show that if $f(t_0)=1$ and for all $\delta>0,$ we have that at least one of $(t_0-\delta,t_0)\cap g^{-1}\bigl[(-\infty,1)\bigr]$ and $(t_0,t_0+\delta)\cap g^{-1}\bigl[(-\infty,1)\bigr]$ is non-empty, then $t_0\in T.$

Once that is shown, you'll have proved that $$T=g^{-1}\bigl[\{1\}\bigr]\cap\Bigl\{t\in\Bbb R\mid\forall \delta>0,(t-\delta,t)\cap g^{-1}\bigl[(-\infty,1)\bigr]\neq\emptyset\text{ or }(t,t+\delta)\cap g^{-1}\bigl[(-\infty,1)\bigr]\neq\emptyset\Bigr\}.$$

Let me know if you have any questions about my answer. Also, let me know if you have any trouble proving the sufficiency, or even if you just want to bounce your proof attempt off of somebody.

Comment: Thank you for your eleborate analysis and answer. However, I'm a PhD-student electrical engineering trying to put some mathematical equations backing up my computer algorithms on my paper. It's an adaptive filter that estimates when a person is sleeping (which is the case when $g(x)\ge1$). I want to compare that with actual sleep onset and wake-up times of a person over say 3 days. $T_{actual}=\{7:15, 23:30, 32:00, 47:15, 56:30, 61:45\}$. for that reason I want to generate the set $T_{estimated}=\{t : g(t)= 1\}$.

Comment: (ran out of chars...) It would be a bit weird to put the formula you suggest in my EE paper, if alone because the reader would not be able to follow it. That's why I tagged my question "notation", which somebody removed and replaced by "real-analysis".

Comment: Cameron, did you not notice that the main question was about what to **denote** the set of values where transitions occur as opposed to give an elaborate way of defining that set.

Comment: @Jyrki: It seemed to me that the OP was denoting the set by $T,$ but wasn't sure how to define it. This was further supported by the exchange in the comments above, where the OP seemed to support a patently incorrect suggestion as a workable answer.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Apologies for not meeting your needs with my answer. Is there anything else you can tell be about the function $g$? Is it differentiable, perhaps? Piecewise linear? Smooth? Anything else you can give me might enable me to simplify my definition. Also, I was the one who removed the notation tag, as it is not appropriate for this question (see the [tag wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/notation/info) for its intended use).

Comment: $g(t)=\frac{100}{1 + \exp\left(\frac{10 - v(t)}{3}\right)}$ is a function of other function $v(t)$, which is part a coupled ODE. They are part of a larger model of sleep regulation.

Comment: I understand that you remove tags. But I'd rather you replace them. Else I'll end up with tag-less questions, that nobody will answer. And could you please elaborate on the "patently incorrect suggestion"?

Comment: The issue with the suggestion $T=g^{-1}\bigl[\{1\}\bigr]$ is as Ethan pointed out in the comments above. In your particular case, let's suppose that $v(t)=1-3\ln(99)$ for all $t.$ Then $g(t)=1$ for all $t,$ so $T=\emptyset,$ but $g^{-1}\bigl[\{1\}\bigr]$ is the whole domain of $v.$ Now, if we knew more about $v,$ then we could perhaps say more.

Comment: If $v$ is a nice enough function, then we might try $T=\mathrm{dom}(f)\setminus\mathrm{dom}(f').$ That is, $T$ will be the set of points in the domain of $f$ at which $f'$ is undefined (due to discontinuity).

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but the direction you are heading is just not useful for me. I'm describing an algorithm based on [this paper](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0748730410369208?url_ver=Z39.88-2003). My output is derived from equation 11 there. The output represents the sleep-wake cycle: one sleep onset time and one wake up time per night. I don't want to prove this mathematically, I just want a set that contains all the sleep onset- and wake up times in 7 days. p.s. could pls you @ me, so I see you responded? I coincidentally checked this page and saw your response.

Comment: @JHBonarius: I'm sorry I forgot to tag you! I suspect (given the situation being modeled) that $\mathrm{dom}(f)\setminus\mathrm{dom}(f')$ will probably be what you're looking for. Hope that helps!